# How to get entities' index in ElasticSearch-Spark

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark, rdd

I am using the [elasticsearch-hadoop/spark](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/tree/master/spark) library to create `Spark` `RDD`s from ElasticSearch queries.

The `esRDD` method returns the raw document (`_source`, in ElasticSearch terms) and the document's id (`_id` in ES), but I also need additional information regarding the returned documents, such as the ElasticSearch index and type each document comes from (this information is always available from the ES REST API).

How can I get the index and type information of documents in the `RDD` returned by the `esRDD` method?

**EDIT**
I am querying multiple indices, i.e. my call to `esRDD` looks like this:

```
sparkContext.esRDD("index*/entities", query)
```

and the actual indices are "index1", "index2", etc.
So, I want to know which specific index each of the entities in the resulting `RDD` came from.

Comment: Please show us some code how you are invoking esRDD, you have to specify index and type in the call to esRDD itself like `sc.esRDD("radio/artists")`. Here radio is index and artists is type.

Comment: @PranavShukla I am using multi-index queries with wildcards. I edited the question to make that clear. Thanks anyway for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this in the future:

The solution was to set the `es.read.metadata` setting to `true` (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#_metadata_when_reading_from_elasticsearch)). This adds a `_metadata` field to each document in the `esRDD`, which contains info such as the document's index, type, id, version, etc.